# wordpress, php: print_r(): Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress

I'm getting this message when trying to access wp-admin.php of my website:

"Fatal error: print_r(): Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in /home/x/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase2.php on line 253"

Around the line 253, there's some statements:

```
// All the things that can stop a page being cached
$cache_this_page = true;
if ( defined( 'DONOTCACHEPAGE' ) ) {
    wp_cache_debug( 'DONOTCACHEPAGE defined. Caching disabled.', 2 );
    $cache_this_page = false;
} elseif ( $wp_cache_no_cache_for_get && false == empty( $_GET ) && false == defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) ) {
    wp_cache_debug( "Non empty GET request. Caching disabled on settings page. " . print_r( $_GET, 1 ), 1 );
    $cache_this_page = false;
}
```

And some other elseif statements after that.

A quick look in WP-forums shows that I'm not alone on this. Some people fixed it deactivating the plugin wp-super-cache, but I prefer an alternative solution, until the devs of this thing fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should pass `true` as the second parameter to print_r(), not `1`.

Comment: this is not true, any value except for false or 0 = true. as to the problem at hand the error occurs exactly at line 253 (it could occur within a function called on this line either). DIsable super cache and all your plugins, chances are its a plugin or theme that has caused this, reactivate one by one.

Comment: As mentioned, deactivating wp-super-cache solves the problem, but that's not really a solution.

Comment: @MatthewG It didn't work. Same error output.

Comment: Remove `. print_r( $_GET, 1 )`. Not ideal, but until they fix it...

Comment: I think they introduced a bug with the latest update. I used to have:
"if ( isset( $wp_super_cache_debug ) && $wp_super_cache_debug ) "
in front of the line. Putting that back in makes the code work again.

Comment: I faced this in a similar context. Used `var_export` instead of `print_r` as a workaround.